# Flutter iOS app: Unable to install, Please try again later

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, firebase, flutter

Using Xcode 12.4 and iPhone with iOS 14.4. Archived my app and uploaded it both to TestFlight and Firebase App Distribution (using Distribution and Ad Hoc profiles respectively). Both getting the error "Unable to install, please try again later".

App from Testflight shows the app icon on home screen but its greyed out. Testflight app passed Beta review but not working for internal or external testers. I did not test with any other versions of Xcode or iOS so not able to determine if it is a new issue.

App from App distribution doesn't even show the icon, instead it shows a blue icon with a white question mark.

Any insights or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Getting the same issue, did you find a workaround?